# Github Action Fail : Publish NPM Package

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-actions

I have a problem with a "publish npm package github action"

```
name: Publish package on NPM

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn build
      - run: npm publish --access=public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

and I have this error :

`npm ERR! code EPRIVATE`
`npm ERR! This package has been marked as private`
`npm ERR! Remove the 'private' field from the package.json to publish it.`

But it isn't private AND it worked from command in VSCode, I just typed "npm publish --access=public", so why isn't it working with my github action ? Seems to do the same thing as I did manually

thanks !

Add `private: false`to `package.json`
Remove `private` property from `package.json`
Delete `package-lock.json` and `npm i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because:

> If you set "private": true in your package.json, then npm will refuse to >publish it.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#private

There could be no `private` field in your `package.json` and you can still get this error:

> Note: Using the --access flag on the npm publish command will only set the package access level on the initial publish of the package. Any subsequent npm publish commands using the --access flag will not have an effect to the access level. To make changes to the access level after the initial publish use npm access.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish#access

That means if you had earlier published the package using a different access
level (like `restricted`, which is default for scoped packages, i.e., packages that start with `@`), then you need to change the access level before trying to publish as `public`.

---

On a side, you need to update `actions/checkout` and `actions/setup-node` to use Node.js `v16`.

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) Finally, it worked because I changed the name I think, but with the details of your answer i'll change others things too :) Thanks for explanation !